# Access content page control from master page using javascript

Tags: javascript, master-pages, contentplaceholder, content-pages

I want to access the content page Ajax combobox control in the master page and that too by using Javascript.

I have been trying the same by using the contentpageholder of the content page, but also one of the problem I get is there are around 10 content pages, so when some other page like Page 1 is opened , the code show object reference exception as contentplaceholder is not matched.

How to get that which content page is opened up?
Also I am not able to get the code working to get the maincontentplaceholder id in master page.

What I have done till now:

```
function accessControlContentPage() {
var txtCont = document.getElementById("Page.Master.FindControl('ContentPlaceHolder1').FindControl('txtContent')").value;
var text=txtCont;
}
```

But this is not working.
Any help with the same?

Comment: Once response is rendered to the client, its not helpful to think in terms of master pages and content pages. It is a single web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested approach is add a specific content place holder controls for such scripts to be placed in the web page you are rendering. Take a look at the following master/content page markup:

Master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="WebApp.PageMethods.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">        
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a content place holder `head` wherein I must write some js functions trying to access the dropdown list in the other content place holder `ContentPlaceHolder1`.

Content page markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApp.PageMethods.WebForm3" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script>
        function foo() {
            var ddl = document.getElementById('<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>');
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Content>
```

Here I didn't have to worry so much about trying to access controls nested in `ContentPlaceHolderID`.

Alternatively, if you don't have that option/freedom, you can always write something as follows in your master page itself:

```
var d = document.getElementById('<%= this.ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("DropDownList1").ClientID %>');
```

Comment: 'ASP.site_master' does not contain a definition for 'ContentPlaceHolder1' and no extension method 'ContentPlaceHolder1' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.site_master' could be found

Comment: This used to come and that is why this way still not working. :(

Comment: That should have been mentioned in the post. Can you peek into the designer.cs file of the master page and verify if ContentPlaceHolder1 exists?

Comment: Wait let me try,and I will accept answer if this will work .:)

Answer (score 0):

Access content page control from master page using javascript

we can find **div id** or **control id** of content page from master page in asp.net

Explanation of content page:-
don't forgot to mention **runat="server"**,

ContentPlaceHolderID="**content_body**"   //observation,

**main_content** is the ID of div tag

MasterPage.master

```
            var d = document.getElementById('<%= this.content_body.FindControl("main_content").ClientID %>');
```

Do whatever you want with **d**

Thank you